# Wireless working but ethernet not working in Ubuntu 14.04 in hp laptop

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:bf:9c:1a:8b:3e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d2bf:9cff:fe1a:8b3e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13157 errors:0 dropped:77 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1599274 (1.5 MB)  TX bytes:187537 (187.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:580187 (580.1 KB)  TX bytes:580187 (580.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2c:33:7a:64:4c:3d  
          inet addr:192.168.1.23  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e33:7aff:fe64:4c3d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13814 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10354 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7648712 (7.6 MB)  TX bytes:2244347 (2.2 MB)
```

**if in case any more info required pls comment**

Answer (score 0):

You have not assigned any IPv4 address to your eth0 adapter.

@DragonLord
I normally use the /etc/network/interfaces file.
Adding an example below for two adapters, one with a static IP and one with a dynamic IP (DHCP).

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.99
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

dns-nameservers 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can you explain how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a [DHCP server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) at the other end of the Ethernet cable that will assign an IP address to the Ethernet interface? If there isn't a DHCP server at the other end, you can assign an IP address, subnet mask and gateway address with the following commands presuming that the gateway address, i.e., the router IP address, should be 192.168.1.1 and that an appropriate IP address might be 192.168.1.33

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.33 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 eth0
```

However, if you control the router or whatever device could be a DHCP server at the other end, which could automatically assign an IP address to your Ubuntu system for its Ethernet interface, check its configuration for the Ethernet interface, since it might have a different IP address that should be used for the gateway address and the wired [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) may be different than the wireless one. If it can provide DHCP service for the wired interface, you might want to enable DHCP for the wired interface and not enter the above commands, but, instead, have the DHCP server assign that information. If you enable DHCP on the router or other device at the other end of the cable for the wired interface, then rebooting the Ubuntu system should lead to it being assigned the appropriate IP configuration for the wired interface.

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing happened to my friend, I tried everything including reinstalling the network driver, assigning IPv4 but nothing worked.

Now this might sound lame but she just plugged in a different ethernet cable and, I don't know how, but it started working. So just give it a try.